# How to check if cursor is in insert row of ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have a `java.sql.ResultSet` object whose data I need to save to the database. The cursor can be at insert row (`moveToInsertRow()` has been called) or at an existing database row. In the first case I need to call `insertRow()` and in the latter case I need to call `updateRow()`. How do I know which one to call?

Of course I can set a flag when `moveToInsertRow()` is called but I thought there would be `isInsertRow()` or something like that? I tried `rowInserted()` but MySQL does not support it and anyway I think it only works after `isInsertRow()` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

`getRow()` returns 0 if there is no current row. That seems to work in my case.

**Edit**: It returns 0 also if the row has been deleted so not a perfect solution. When I call `deleteRow()` I will call `close()` after that. Then I can use `isClosed()` to check if it's deleted. `rowDeleted()` is not supported by MySQL JDBC.